# jQuery hasClass() method is not returning correct value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

#### Hi...

I am trying to change the background color of the element and it's children.So I wrote a `function`which is being called recursively. 

    Here are the some conditions that the element's background color should not be changed if it has an attribute `class="irmNDrdnVal"` or `id="irmNDatePickerContainer"`.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC>
<html>
<style>
 .newClass{
  color:red;
  background:green;
 }
</style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="main">
  <span id= "drdn-box-ACNT" class="irmNDrdnInputBox" disabled= "true">
      <input id="drdn-ip-ACNT" class="irmNDrdnInput" readOnly="readOnly" value="1 IA" type="text">
      <span><img src="/sap/bc/bsp/sap/public/drdn-btn.gif"></span>
  </span>
  <div id= "drdn-val-ACNT" class="irmNDrdnVal">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li disabled= "true" key= "">&nbsp;</li>
                <li disabled= "true" key= "1">1 IA</li>
                <li disabled= "true" key= "2">2 PB &amp; CB</li>
                <li disabled= "true" key= "3">3 DM-P</li>
                <li disabled= "true" key= "4">4 DM-R</li>
                <li disabled= "true" key= "5">5 Cash App</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
  function changeBgColor(_ele,_cls,_remove){
    if(_remove){
     _ele.removeClass(_cls);
    }
    else{
     if(!_ele.hasClass('ui-resizable-handle') && !_ele.hasClass('irmNDrdnVal') && _ele.attr('id') != 'irmNDatePickerContainer'){
         _ele.addClass(_cls);
     }
    }
    if(_ele.children().length > 0 && !_ele.hasClass('irmNDrdnVal') && _ele.attr('id') != 'irmNDatePickerContainer'){
      changeBgColor(_ele.children(),_cls,_remove);
    }
  }

 $('div#main').each(function(){
   changeBgColor($(this),'newClass',false);
 });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So I am checking that whether the particular element has class `irmNDrdnVal`.I will allow to change background if only it doesnt have class `'irmNDrdnVal'`.

It is working every element except for one element.i.e

```
<span id= "drdn-box-ACNT" class="irmNDrdnInputBox" disabled= "true">
```

Though it does not have class `'irmNDrdnVal'`, the `hasClass('irmNDrdnVal')` method returns `true` for the element.

I am unable to understand whtz going wrong.

Can somebody help me out.....Thanks in advance...

Comment: Good thing you're keeping it simple and readable, with short describing ID's and classes. Makes it so much easier to find errors ?

Comment: Did you try just doing `_ele.not('.irmNDrdnVal')`

Comment: @adeneo What does that mean? it is returning an object rather than boolean flag..

Comment: Of course it is, my bad, was thinking of the opposite `(!_ele.is('.irmNDrdnVal'))`

Comment: @adeneo _ele.is('.irmNDrdnVal') is also returning `true`....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the code is unreadable, but I guess the problem is here:

```
changeBgColor(_ele.children(), _cls, _remove);
```

If you pass all children to changeBgColor, then all of them will be in _ele (which is jQuery set of elements), and if just only one of children elements has the class irmNDrdnVal then _ele.hasClass('irmNDrdnVal') will return true for the whole set. Try to change it like

```
_ele.children().each(function(){
   changeBgColor($(this), _cls, _remove);
})
```

And also, try to keep you code more readable for debugging purposes ;)

Comment: I'll upvote that, as it seems plausible! Looked like the function was only being passed #main, and why anyone would need to loop over ID's which are supposed to be unique is another question, but I did'nt notice the function calling itself in a loop with all the children being passed. On the other hand, who knows, as that entire script is totally unreadable with long strange classes and if / else statements that are almost impossible to read.